# #include <fstream> visual c++ 2010 not working properly

Tags: c++, visual-c++, namespaces, std, using

I know that the title is a little vague but i can't think of a better title right now. 
The extract from my code looks like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
int main(){
ifstream f("cuvinte.txt");
f.getline(cuvant);
return 0;
}
```

When i want to read the next word from "cuvinte.txt" i write f.getline(cuvant); but i get the following error

```
error C2661: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::getline' : no overloaded function takes 1 arguments
```

I don't know what the issue is, and i stumbled upon this problem a while ago and still can't get past it.

Comment: It's working properly, you just aren't using it properly. If a standard function fails, it's most likely your fault.

Comment: @Cubic read "most likely" as "definitely".

Comment: I wouldn't exclude the possibility of the implementation of the standard library being buggy, but I guess thats rare enough to say 'definitely'.

Comment: Indeed the title is not the best and i know it was my fault. From what i've learned in highschool it was supposed to work like this. But i'll just have to adapt to the new ways.

Comment: What is Cuvant? It isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: It is just an extract from a whole.

Comment: @Edeph If by new you mean before 1998 that is. istream::getline always worked like this.

Comment: New to me. I'm at the very beginning of programming and it's intimidating at a first glance. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't know what the issue is, and i stumbled upon this problem a
> while ago and still can't get past it.

To the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline)!

```
basic_istream& getline( char_type* s, std::streamsize count );
```

You need to provide the size, i.e. the amount of available space in `cuvant`.

```
f.getline(cuvant, size);
                  ^^^^
```

---

#### EDIT

An alternative would be to use more modern instruments:

```
string cuvant;
getline(f, cuvant);
```

Comment: But if i read the word from the file, how am i supposed to know it's size ?

Comment: @Edeph You're not. You need to specify a maximum size. I'd go with `std::getline` instead.

Comment: I just give it a maximum value and i see it works. Thank you! (I would upvote your answer but i don't have enough reputation)

Answer (score 1):

You seem a little shaky on your familiarity with the various forms of getline.  Here are a few simple uses of it for your reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string filepath = "test.txt";               // name of the text file
    string buffer;                              // buffer to catch data in
    string firstLine;                           // the first line of the file will be put here

    ifstream fin;

    fin.open(filepath);                         // Open the file
    if(fin.is_open())                           // If open succeeded
    {
        // Capture first line directly from file
        getline(fin,firstLine,'\n');            // Capture first line from the file.
        cout << firstLine << '\n';              // Prove we got it.

        fin.seekg(0,ios_base::beg);             // Move input pointer back to the beginning of the file.

        // Load file into memory first for faster reads,
        // then capture first line from a stringstream instead
        getline(fin,buffer,'\x1A');             // Capture entire file into a string buffer
        istringstream fullContents(buffer);     // Put entire file into a stringstream.
        getline(fullContents,firstLine,'\n');   // Capture first line from the stringstream instead of from the file.
        cout << firstLine << '\n';              // Prove we got it.

        fin.close();                            // Close the file
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Using the following sample file:

```
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
This is the last line.
```

You will get the following output:

```
This is the first line.
This is the first line.
```

Answer (score 0):

The prototypes for `getline` are:

```
istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n );
istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );
```

so, as the error message clearly states, you can't call it with one argument...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `cuvant` is an `std::string`, the correct call is

```
std::getline(f, cuvant);
```